# Why function clone of jQuery work only first time?

Tags: jquery

i use jquery clone to save my element in a variable.
If I try to insert my element in the dom the events only work the first time.

```js
var tableStructure; 

var clicca = 0;
$(document).ready( function () {

    $('#myElement').click(function(){
    alert('Hello world!');
  });
  
  $('#btnTest').click(function(){
    clicca++
    if(!tableStructure) tableStructure = $('#myElement').clone(true,true);
    $('#container > div').remove();
    $( tableStructure ).insertAfter( '#btnTest' );
    $('#numberClick > span').html(clicca);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="margin-bottom:20px">
<button id="btnTest" style="margin-bottom:20px">
Remove, clone and Append
</button>

<div id="myElement" style="cursor:pointer"><b>click me</b></div>
</div>

<div id="numberClick">
Number of click: <span>0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use `$(document).on("click","#myElement",function() {})`. Problem is that your click event is bound to the object and you do remove that object. so even though it has the "Same" id, it's not bound to that object any more

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you have bound a click event to your `#myElement`. But when cloning that element the click event is no longer bound.

You can use this: `$(document).on("click","#myElement",function() {})`

**Demo**

```js
var tableStructure;

var clicca = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click", "#myElement", function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
  });

  $('#btnTest').click(function() {
    clicca++
    if (!tableStructure) tableStructure = $('#myElement').clone(true, true);
    $('#container > div').remove();
    $(tableStructure).insertAfter('#btnTest');
    $('#numberClick > span').html(clicca);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="margin-bottom:20px">
  <button id="btnTest" style="margin-bottom:20px">
Remove, clone and Append
</button>

  <div id="myElement" style="cursor:pointer"><b>click me</b></div>
</div>

<div id="numberClick">
  Number of click: <span>0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood his problem. It's a very odd scenario.